# Google Analytics mix two differents goals with logic conditions

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

in Google Analytics i have two differents goals already setted.
1 - users that watch site more than 3 Mins
2 - users that watch more than 2 pages

I need to have another goal(or something similar to show in dashboard) that mix these two goals togheter with logic conditions.
So this is the goal requested.

3 - users that Watch site more than 3 Min and/or Watch more than 2 pages. (For unique users)

I've tried with goals but i don't think it's the way. I think it's segment the way to go (in user view to have unique user data) but i don't know how. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tag for [tag:google-analytics] says: "Questions related to Google Analytics data or usage should be submitted to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/."

Answer (score 0):

Note that goals in GA count conversions for session, not for user.

If you need track for users, there are 2 ways: event or segment. Is you are good in JS, create event for unique user when 2 conditions are completed. In this case you can create a goal, it's good for dashboards.

Or create segment in GA using your existing goals. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, today i'll try with the event way that seems correct for my purpose. But for unique user should i use user view?

Comment: What do you mean user view?